# Problema de CORS en iframe

Tags: javascript

me podrian ayudar con esta problematica?
Estoy insertando un stringBase64 de un archivo pdf en una etiqueta iframe

```
const embedctn = document.querySelector('#embedctn')
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe')

iframe.type = "application/pdf"
iframe.src = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + base64
iframe.width = '100%'
iframe.height = '100%'
iframe.id = 'iframeId'
```

Luego de crear el iframe, lo inserto dentro de un div en el html

```
embedctn.appendChild(iframe)
```

Luego de insertar el iframe, quiero usar la funcion print() para que me aparezca el modal de impresion

```
setTimeout(()=>{
  const fr = document.querySelector('#iframeId')
  fr.focus()
  fr.contentWindow.print()
},2000)
```

Pero me arroja un problema de cors y no se como resolverlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]